# Need Mysql Zabbix data for CPU utilization, memory utilization, Disk space utilization for creating ML profile

Tags: mysql, machine-learning, zabbix

I have installed Zabbix 4.0 for remote monitoring of Linux server. My first understanding is that the Zabbix-agent monitors the server and send the data to Mysql database for storing. The Zabbix frontend retrieves the data from Mysql database and shows the above-said metrics (in the form of graphs), as shown in the attached image.[image: of CPU load]

Now, instead of directly viewing from the web interface, I want to construct the ML model from metrics like `CPU utilization/load`, `memory utilization`, `hard disk usage`, and `traffic in/out`. I checked all the `Columns` of all the `Tables` in Mysql database to retrieve the above-said metrics. However, I could not find any columns or tables that stored these metrics. My second is understanding is that Zabbix front-end constructs these metrics on graph indirectly from the stored columns in Mysql databse Tables.

1. I want to know if my both the understandings are correct or no.
2. I also want to know, considering my both understandings are true, how do i extract metrics like `CPU utilization/load`, `memory utilization`, `hard disk usage`, and `traffic in/out` for constructing ML model from data that is stored in Mysql database.
3. If my understandings are false, how should I collect these metrics.

Any details or documentation that could help me is appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zabbix data is stored in the Mysql database in various tables (history and trends, differentiated by data type). 
The difference between history and trend is described [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/history_and_trends).

I strongly advise against the direct use of mysql, because of complexity and compatibility.
The best course of action is through the API ([`history.get`](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/api/reference/history/get) and [`trend.get`](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/api/reference/trend/get)) to extract the data and feed it to your ML.

Zabbix itself supports [predictive triggering](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/triggers/prediction), but I did not implement it yet.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know my question was way too broad, but instead of just downvoting, you gave me a direction to look into.

Comment: On top of that, partial  documentation is available at https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/DB_schema/3.4/hosts .